# ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

Newbee here. Kindly explain **why this issue happened and how to fix it.**

**Error:**

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" C:/Users/Vivek-Pc/PycharmProjects/tryOutSeries/searchTryout2.py
>   Exception ignored in: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in **del**
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 149, in stop
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 120, in send_remote_shutdown_command
>   ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
>   Process finished with exit code 0

**Code Used:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver_path = "c:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver"
b_obj = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
b_obj.implicitly_wait(15)
b_obj.maximize_window()
b_obj.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

search_box = b_obj.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys("Selenium")
search_box.submit()
b_obj.close()
```

**Environment Info:**

> Windows, Selenium, Python, Chrome (chromedriver.exe) & PyCharm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've reproduced the same error using Python 3.6, Selenium 3.0.2 and ChromeDriver 2.27 (everything latest at this point).

The problem appears to happen when the Python selenium webdriver tries to [stop the `chromedriver` service](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L170) either when you explicitly close the driver, or when the script execution simply ends (and the `__del__` method gets to be executed).

Reported the issue to Python/Selenium github issue tracker:

- [sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3330)

**Workaround:**

I found that using `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()` helps to workaround the problem.

Comment: Just to let you know. Even without using driver.quit() or driver.close(), getting the same error.  <error> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" D:/iqz/my-works/automation-practice/practice/selenium-tryout/firefoxSearch.py
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, ................Python is likely shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
</error>

Comment: Code used: from selenium import webdriver
path1 = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Edge(path1)
browser.get("https://www.google.com/")

Answer (score 3):

you can also give time for the quit method to finish execution before python exit.
this worked for me :

```
#right before quitting
driver.quit()
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have hit the same issue while working on CLI Automation project.

To get rid of this, you have to close the opened objects such as:

1. If working on Paramiko, have to close the opened handlers
   **client.close()
   shell.close()**
2. If working on file operations then
    **file_handler.close()**
3. if working on sockets then we have close the objects created on it.

Comment: `Paramiko` was the issue for me. Had to manually close the connection. Thanks.