# Unexpected error while working with beautifulsoup and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project that requires me to extract data from a webpage.
For starting, I have used the following code to build my system. Note - I'm using PyCharm IDE and chrome.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.snapdeal.com/product/skycandle-bfm-single-bucket-mop/684185386697#bcrumbSearch:skycandle')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.prettify())
```

An instance of Chrome opens with the page that i've mentioned in the code. But the expected output of '.prettify()' doesn't come up. 
I get the following error -

```
    *
```

*

```
C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/kp/PycharmProjects/scrap_selenium/prog.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/kp/PycharmProjects/scrap_selenium/prog.py", line 28, in <module>
        html = driver.page_source
      File "C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 500, in page_source
        return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
      File "C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 237, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
    from unknown error: web view not found
      (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

    Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x0353C810>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 162, in __del__
      File "C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 138, in stop
      File "C:\Users\kp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in send_remote_shutdown_command
    ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

*

*

Please rectify!

Comment: Your script works, so the problem is elsewhere. Could you retry adding `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` after the print ?

Comment: Done, but still the problem persists.

Comment: The problem seems [known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480148/importerror-sys-meta-path-is-none-python-is-likely-shutting-down). Try using Firefox Driver or Phantom JS instead of Chrome()

Comment: Will try. Thanks!