# `undetected_chromedriver` silently fails

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a pretty standard boilerplate undetected_chromedriver installation:

```py
LOCAL_CHRPATH = '/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver'
driver = uc.Chrome(
        driver_executable_path=LOCAL_CHRPATH, headless=True
)
```

However, `driver.get(url)` simply fails silently, exiting the program. I have looked through the documentation, and found no way to get diagnostics pre or post `get`. Any idea of what to do or where to check?

You can pretty much ignore the specifics about the path and so on; the real question here is to understand why it fails.

*Update*: if I set `debug` to True, I get the same error that's indicated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480148/importerror-sys-meta-path-is-none-python-is-likely-shutting-down). However, don't see a workaround for that. As an indication, this was working correctly with Python 3.10, stopped working when downgrading to 3.9

Comment: does it exit with a code? I mean, do you sen "exit with code -1" or something in the terminal?

Comment: @NicoCaldo it's run from poetry, maybe that hides the exit value. But I guess it does, since it's exiting prematurely. Would codes give me some information?

Comment: it's a first indication on what happened. exit 1 usually is when some sort of error happens

Comment: @NicoCaldo I know an error has happened, it simply does not work. I want to know which one.

Answer (score 0):

`LOCAL_CHRPATH = '/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver'`

This is local variable, not environmental. To set envvar you could:

`os.environ["LOCAL_CHRPATH"] = '/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver'`

Or just don't use envvars, or set default value:

```
driver = uc.Chrome(
    driver_executable_path=os.getenv('LOCAL_CHRPATH', LOCAL_CHRPATH), 
    headless=True
)
```

Comment: I know it's confusing to have them both with the same name, but what I do is to set the env variable to 1 and if it's set, use the preset path as the value. The path is set correctly. Maybe I'll just edit to avoid confusion