# ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down; OverflowError: timeout doesn't fit into C timeval; Exception in thread Thread-1

Tags: python, sh, yolo, federated-learning

I got a series of error messages, the last one being the one mentioned first in the title, while I was trying to run [this](https://github.com/MenguChen/Federated_object_detection) Github repo on my local machine. I need that project as a boilerplate for my own code later.

I have pasted the dependencies and the error at the end.

**My Tries to solve it:**
I have looked at the answers for a similar error in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480148/importerror-sys-meta-path-is-none-python-is-likely-shutting-down) post, but I could not figure out the solution for my case. I have also looked into answers for the `Exception in thread Thread-1` and `OverflowError: timeout doesn't fit into C timeval`  anomalies which were in the same log, but am completely helpless.
I also tried changing from a conda environment to virtualenv environment but I ran into the same error. I also tried with Python v3.9 and 3.10.9 and 3.10.10

**Things to look for, while running the cloned project:**

- There is no need to prepare the dataset as it already comes with the cloned project. Follow the rest of the steps as in the Readme.
- You can look at the logs for the server in the `C:\Users\HP\Federated_object_detection\experiments\logs\0307\yolo\street_5`  directory.
- 'I got the error' in the client's log files which are in `C:\Users\HP\Federated_object_detection\yolo_task1`  and all 4 others.
- Remember to download the weights `darknet53.conv.74` in `C:\Users\HP\Federated_object_detection\weights`
- Change the python directory to your conda/virtualenv environment's python, in the `run_server` and `run` shell scripts, before running them. 'I ran those scripts in Git Bash.'
- The dependencies below should help.

**Dependencies**

```
bidict==0.22.1
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.0.7
cupy-cuda11x==11.6.0
cycler==0.11.0
Cython==0.29.33
dnspython==2.3.0
eventlet==0.33.3
fastrlock==0.8.1
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.2
fonttools==4.39.0
greenlet==2.0.2
idna==3.4
imageio==2.26.0
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
jsonpatch==1.32
jsonpointer==2.3
kiwisolver==1.4.4
lazy_loader==0.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.7.1
networkx==3.0
numpy==1.24.2
packaging==23.0
Pillow==9.4.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-engineio==3.14.2
python-socketio==4.6.1
PyWavelets==1.4.1
requests==2.28.2
scikit-image==0.20.0
scipy==1.9.1
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0.post1
socketIO-client==0.7.2
terminaltables==3.1.10
tifffile==2023.2.28
torch==1.13.1
torchnet==0.0.4
torchvision==0.14.1
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
urllib3==1.26.14
visdom==0.2.4
websocket-client==1.5.1
Werkzeug==2.0.3
zipp==3.15.0
```

**Error**

```
Namespace(gpu=2, config_file='data/task_configs/yolo/street_5/yolo_task2.json', ignore_load='True', port=1234)
client run on 2
{'model_name': 'Yolo', 'model_config': 'data/task_configs/yolo/street_5/yolo_model.json', 'log_filename': 'yolo/street_5/FL_client_2_log', 'train': 'data/street_5/2/train.txt', 'test': 'data/street_5/2/test.txt', 'names': 'data/street_5/classes.names', 'n_cpu': 4, 'local_epoch': 5, 'batch_size': 1}
INFO:client:{'model_name': 'Yolo', 'model_config': 'data/task_configs/yolo/street_5/yolo_model.json', 'log_filename': 'yolo/street_5/FL_client_2_log', 'train': 'data/street_5/2/train.txt', 'test': 'data/street_5/2/test.txt', 'names': 'data/street_5/classes.names', 'n_cpu': 4, 'local_epoch': 5, 'batch_size': 1}
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
sent wakeup
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Federated_object_detection\fl_client.py", line 266, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\heartbeats.py", line 27, in run
    FederatedClient("127.0.0.1", opt.port, opt.config_file, opt.gpu, opt.ignore_load)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Federated_object_detection\fl_client.py", line 95, in __init__
    self._send_heartbeat()
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 210, in _ping
    self.sio.emit('client_wake_up')
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 433, in emit
    self._transport_instance.send_packet(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 94, in send_packet
    self._message(str(socketIO_packet_type) + socketIO_packet_data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 28, in wrap
    get_response(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 176, in get_response
    return f(*args, **kw)
    response = request(*args, stream=True, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 225, in _message
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 635, in post
    transport.send_packet(engineIO_packet_type, engineIO_packet_data)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 94, in send_packet
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    get_response(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 176, in get_response
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    response = request(*args, stream=True, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 635, in post
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 434, in _make_request
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    conn.sock.settimeout(read_timeout)
OverflowError: timeout doesn't fit into C timeval
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 82, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
OverflowError: timeout doesn't fit into C timeval
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 203, in _close
    self._transport_instance.send_packet(engineIO_packet_type)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 94, in send_packet
    get_response(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 176, in get_response
    response = request(*args, stream=True, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 635, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 82, in create_connection
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
OverflowError: timeout doesn't fit into C timeval
Exception ignored in: <function SocketIO.__del__ at 0x000001E2405CB820>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 372, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 417, in disconnect
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\__init__.py", line 203, in _close
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 94, in send_packet
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\socketIO_client\transports.py", line 176, in get_response
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 635, in post
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in request
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in prepare_request
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 556, in merge_cookies
  File "C:\Users\HP\menguv2\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 362, in update
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 92, in copy
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

**Previous errors:**
Just mentioning it in case it helps. I was facing issues with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069215/the-client-is-using-an-unsupported-version-of-the-socket-io-or-engine-io-protoco) which I solved by installing `Flask-SocketIO==4.3.2` and other related dependencies.